# Обход всех расстановок в Пятнашках

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация

Вспомнил одну интересную задачу. Возможно её даже лучше решать математику, а не программисту. Практического применения не вижу, кроме как размять мозг.

Есть игра Пятнашки: поле 4 на 4, 15 плашек с числами от 1 до 15 и можно перемещать плашки по одной на свободное место не вынимая из коробки. **Задача**: определить максимальное количество ходов, необходимое для решения головоломки. Наиболее логичное решение - обход в ширину всего дерева вариантов расстановок плашек. Но дерево очень большое, поэтому хочется научиться эффективно хранить множество уже пройденных расстановок и работать с ним.

Всего возможных расстановок 16!, т.е. около 20.9 триллиона. Занумеровать их проблем нет. И даже нет проблем отбросить половину, недостижимую из исходной расстановки 1, 2, …, 15, пусто. Но даже если завести по битику на каждое состояние – чтобы хранить, встречалась ли расстановка, потребуется 1.3 ТБ памяти. Даже если бы у меня было столько места на диске, я думаю, алгоритм работал бы смертельно медленно из-за того, что по мере обхода дерева расстановок в ширину доступ к диску получается хаотичный.

Соответственно, хорошим решением было бы придумать нумерацию, при которой соседние расстановки имеют близкие номера. Но дерево имеет довольно хитрую форму, поэтому это не так-то просто. Как вариант решения - доказать, что это невозможно. Либо придумать нечто совсем иное.

За базовый алгоритм нумерации расстановок я брал примерно следующий. Берём число на левой верхней плашке, умножаем на 15. Помечаем, что число на этой плашке встретилось. Теперь берём следую плашку и находим номер числа на ней среди всех чисел, которые ещё не встречались. Прибавляем к предыдущему произведению и умножаем на 14. И т.д. Если встречаем пустое место, то ничего не прибавляем.

Некоторого улучшения удавалось добиться кодированием плашек в другой последовательности. Например, смотрим на четверть, в которой находится пустое место. Сначала кодируем числа на плашках в четверти, находящейся от неё по диагонали, потом – в двух соседних и наконец – собственно в ней.

Кому интересно, ещё есть моя же давнишняя публикация на эту тему: [Исследование решения игры "пятнашки"](http://ambitiousdev-ru.blogspot.com/2010/09/blog-post.html). Там есть результаты для поля 4 на 3.

Comment: Я помню решал эту задачу с помощью A*. Хранил узлы дерева вроде бы нумеровал как-то незамысловато, чуть ли не списком всех чисел по-порядку справа-налево, сверху-вниз. Считало достаточно долго, но памяти на ноутбуке хватало, засчет того, что A* не дает сильно расходится в ширину по дереву.

Comment: @dzhioev, Вы уверены, что памяти хватало, для 4*4? А если начальную расстановку взять потяжелее? 


Когда я делал поиск решения для одной расстановки, у меня начали получаться нормальные результаты только после того, как я избавился от std::set и std::map и сделал более-менее хорошую функцию оценки. Тратилось, помнится, порядка 100 МБ памяти и 10 секунд для решений порядка 50 ходов. Кстати, я там выбрасывал варианты (для экономии памяти), так что 100%-й гарантии оптимальности решения я не имел. Для 70-тиходовых расстановок ситуацию не помню

Comment: Строго говоря, я знаю ответ, максимум - 80 ходов. Я получил его поиском в интернете. Была какая-то интересная статья про распараллеливание на кластер. Фишка в том, чтобы это соптимизировать и решить на одном компьютере

Comment: @Михаил М, я раскопал сорцы, если интересно могу выложить куда-нибудь вечерком.

Comment: @dzhioev, в принципе, выложите, если там не сильно сложно. 



Кстати, да, у меня ещё была таблица решений шагов на 15 - вместо встречного поиска :)

Comment: https://github.com/dzhioev/15solver . Там немного сложнее алгоритм, он поддерживает поля произвольного размера + "стены" на поле. Как запускать для стандартных пятнашек можно посмотреть в main. Сейчас позапускал -- в среднем находит решение за 1-2 секунды. Возможно решение "немного" неточное, т.к. алгоритм останавливается при первой встрече поисков с разных сторон, а после этого кажется еще какие-то телодвижения надо делать, чтобы получить точный результат.

Comment: Я наконец прочитал внимательно ваш вопрос и понял, что вы хотели =). Моя программка просто находит расстояние от одного положения до другого =).

Comment: Так и есть, к сожалению :)



Очень интересно, посравнивал Ваш поиск решения и свой. Несмотря на то, что Вы по-простому храните std::set<std::vector<int> >, а у меня - куча ухищрений (даже есть свой аллокатор), результаты - примерно одинаковые. Т.е. у меня просматривается раз в 20 больше вариантов за сравнимое время, но решение находится такое же или на пару шагов короче. 



Похоже, волшебный секрет - встречный поиск. Даже мой предварительный расчёт на 14 шагов из конечной расстановки не очень помогает - видимо, потому что встречный поиск идёт в направлении именно нужной исходной расстановки

Answer (score 1):

Я придумал такой алгоритм, вроде бы корректный:
[image]
Как видим, хранить все пройденные расстановки не надо, только два предыдущих "поколения". Более того, все шаги хорошо реализуются с помощью алгоритмов во внешней памяти, т.е. таких алгоритмов, для которых нет нужды помещать все данные в оперативную память. Тут нам понадобятся только сортировка, удаление дупликатов, слияние множеств и разность множеств. Про сортировку можно почитать, например, [на википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting), остальное не сложно.

Мне кажется, что имея пару ТБ жестких дисков, можно эту задачу за приемлемое время решить на любом современном компьютере.

Comment: Ну это простейший алгоритм обхода в ширину. Как бы да. 



Но в наиболее жирных "поколениях" будет миллиардов по 300 расстановок. Это 2 ТБ только на 64-битные коды. При этом, чтобы сгенерировать следующее понадобится прочитать эти 2 ТБ, сгенерировать 2-4 соседние расстановки для каждой имеющейся, и как-то их отсортировать. Ну допустим мы заведём "отстойник" на 4 ГБ и будем там складывать коды перед сортировкой. Как накопилось 4 ГБ - сортировать за N*log N и вливать в отсортированные вторые 2 ТБ. И это - приблизительно 600 раз на одно "поколение"... Несколько месяцев, однако :)

Comment: Хотя, если сделать по аналогии с внешней сортировкой, может получиться нормально. Т.е. можно сохранять отсортированные куски, допустим, по те же 4 ГБ, сохранять их на диск, а потом их все одновременно читать (с буферизацией) и сливать. Если удастся сделать скорость обработки достаточной, чтобы загрузить винчестер работой, можно рассчитывать на несколько часов/шаг. Этакая умная грубая сила